# How to change Razer Mamba "sensitivity stage up" shortkey?

Tags: mouse

Is it possible to change button "sensitivity stage up" or "down", to any other keyboard key?

For example I want change to "Enter" the shortkey for "sensitivity stage up".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the mamba configurator the 6th and 7th buttons are the sensitivity buttons. Just re affect them to "one key" and set  as key. Hit ok and apply. You're done.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to move the sensitivity away from the mouse to give me more mouse buttons for key assignment. For some games I just want 2 dpi settings and I really wanted 1 mouse button for toggling rather than shifting up and down and wasting a precious button.

To get around this I created 2 identical profiles albeit with different DPI settings. I assigned one of the dpi sensitivity buttons to switching profiles and freed up one button.